# ApiGiltiy: Unable to fetch API filesystem writability status

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I recently started to get this error while using ApiGility. I am unaware of any particular change that may have caused it:

```
Unable to fetch API filesystem writability status; you may need to refresh the page.
```

In addition to this error, I also get this one:

```
Unable to fetch API opcode cache status; you may need to refresh the page.
```

Any idea how I should go about bug testing it?

One solution that was posted was to comment out some code in ApiGility however this does not sound like a reasonable fix to me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I am using ZfcRbac and I had the permissions set to:

```
'zfc_rbac' => [
    'protection_policy' => \ZfcRbac\Guard\GuardInterface::POLICY_DENY
]
```

Comment: Funny how one comes back to the same problem and thank goodnes for SO to remind me of the fix.